# Do I have to solve a 4th degree equation to find $\cos\alpha$ from $d + t \cos(\alpha) = w \tan(\alpha)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

I have the following situation:

[image]

I know $w$, $d$ and $t$. What I want to know is $\alpha$ respectively $\cos(\alpha)$.

I have to solve the following formula for $\alpha$:

> $$d + t \cos(\alpha) = w \tan(\alpha)$$

respectively

$$d + t \cos(\alpha) = w \frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos(\alpha)^2}}{\cos(\alpha)}$$

That leads to a 4th degree equation.

$$d^2 + 2dt \cos(\alpha) + t^2 \cos^2(\alpha) = w^2\frac{1 - \cos^2(\alpha)}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

> $$d^2 \cos^2(\alpha) + 2dt \cos^3(\alpha) + t^2 \cos^4(\alpha) = w^2 (1 - \cos^2(\alpha))$$

My question is

> Do I miss something? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: By the way, the issue is related to a roof editor in a CAD system [YouTube - video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq4UV-MDU9U&t=)

Comment: You were missing a coefficient of $t^2$ in your last two equations; I took the liberty of adding them in. That done, I get the same result as you. There are other ways of attacking the problem (say, with the [half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)), but a quartic appears inevitable.

Comment: I take it this is a roof rafter: you can probably set $t=0$ as a first approximation in order to develop an iterative solution.